# How to print only selected checkboxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, printing

How can I do possible using the standard browser print menu, print only selected images by checkboxes? Using javascript, of course. Thanks in advance!
My code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foto1" value="foto1"> <img src="1.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto2" value="foto2"> <img src="2.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto3" value="foto3"> <img src="3.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto4" value="foto4"> <img src="4.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto5" value="foto5"> <img src="5.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto6" value="foto6"> <img src="6.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto7" value="foto7"> <img src="7.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto8" value="foto8"> <img src="8.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto9" value="foto9"> <img src="9.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto10" value="foto10"> <img src="10.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto11" value="foto11"> <img src="11.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto12" value="foto12"> <img src="12.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto13" value="foto13"> <img src="13.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto14" value="foto14"> <img src="14.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto15" value="foto15"> <img src="15.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto16" value="foto16"> <img src="16.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto17" value="foto17"> <img src="17.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto18" value="foto18"> <img src="18.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto19" value="foto19"> <img src="19.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto20" value="foto20"> <img src="20.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto21" value="foto21"> <img src="21.jpg"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="foto22" value="foto22"> <img src="22.jpg"><br>

<a href=# onClick="window.print();">Print</a>
```

Comment: You could simply hide the unchecked boxes before calling `window.print()`

Comment: The best thing you can do is create a separate css with print rules, then, add a class to checked boxes through javascript before calling `window.print()`. Hiding boxes directly also works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like the following, using media-queries:

```
@media print {
    /* hides all img elements that are adjacent to an input element: */
    input[type=checkbox],
    #printButtonElementID, 
    input[type=checkbox] + img {
        display: none;
    }
    /* shows all img elements directly adjacent to a checked input
       of type=checkbox: */
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + img {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

References:

- [Media Queries (at MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: I would also add `a` and `input` to `display:none` so just images are visible for print

Comment: @Yesian: I thought about that, but it wasn't mentioned in the question so I opted to leave it out. I may add it in though, but tomorrow: I think I need to go to sleep now... :-/

Comment: @DavidThomas :) sleep well

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you, it's works. But how can I hide checkboxes and print button when I'm printing?

Comment: Add that to the print stylesheet?

Comment: @DavidThomas Am I right? input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display:none;
}
input[type="button"]
{
    display:none;
}

Comment: That should do it, if you look at the updated answer I've shown one approach (though I assumed you were targeting 'the print button' by its `id`, rather than *all* buttons).

Answer (score 0):

**Using javascript** as your post mentioned:

I think it will be something like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked + img')
```

Here is an **[online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v5G32/)**